# Add PCLHistogramVisualizer to Qt interface

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library

Following the tutorial [Create a PCL visualizer in Qt with cmake](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php) it is very easy and understandable how to add [`PCLVisualizer`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html) to your QT interface using a [`QVTKWidget`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classQVTKWidget.html). I want to do the same with a [`PCLHistogramVisualizer`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_histogram_visualizer.html) (add it to a QT user interface). Can somebody point me out how to do it? I have not been able to find a tutorial such as the one for the [`PCLVisualizer`](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/qt_visualizer.php). The problem is that I have not found a replacement for this two actions:

```
ui->qvtkWidget->SetRenderWindow (viewer->getRenderWindow ()); 
viewer->setupInteractor (ui->qvtkWidget->GetInteractor (), ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow ());
```

where `viewer` is of type [`pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.1/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html) and `ui->qvtkWidget` is of type [`QVTKWidget`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classQVTKWidget.html).

Thank you very much.